# JQ: PigLatin style FLATTEN function

Tags: json, apache-pig, flatten, jq

I have been looking for a quite specific feature that may not exist in `jq`. If you know that it's not there, I would appreciate a kind notice and some suggestion to solve this problem.

I am processing a public [dataset](http://journals.aps.org/datasets). I have managed to reduce the data into the following line format:

```
[field1,field2,field3,[author1,...,authorN],[author_type1,...,author_typeN]]
```

The bash command I am using to get to this format is the following:

```
find aps-dataset-metadata_subdir_path/ -name '*.json' | \
xargs cat | \
jq --compact-output \
    'select(.authors != null) | [.identifiers.doi, .date, .journal.id, [.authors[].name], [.authors[].type]]'
```

Notice that the `authorN` and `author_typeN` are in the same object (i.e. having the same parent) in the raw data.

I have been looking for a way to produce from each of these line the following:

```
[field1,field2,field3,author1,author_type1]
[field1,field2,field3,author2,author_type2]
...
...
[field1,field2,field3,authorN,author_typeN]
```

The flatten function in `jq` seems to be level-flattening without generating new lists. If some of you knows PigLatin, what I want is exactly the [PigLatin built-in Flatten](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch06.html) operator.

Again, I am aware of the possibility that it is not implemented in `jq`. In that case probably I will post-process the output in `Python`, or any other awesome way that you guys suggest in answers.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than going through the authors separately in separate expressions, you need to go through the authors once.  You could put the results in a variable and access them later.

```
select(.authors != null) | .authors[] as $author |
    [ .identifiers.doi, .date, .journal.id, $author.name, $author.type ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Jeff's suggestion to use a one-step approach makes sense, but if one did have to translate the array `[field1,field2,field3,[author1,...,authorN],[author_type1,...,author_typeN]]` to a stream of arrays of the form `[field1,field2,field3,authorI,author_typeI]` then a suitable jq filter would be:

```
.[0:2] + ([.[3], .[4]] | transpose[])
```